# Running command lines within your Python script

Tags: python, windows, cmd

So I have a bunch of aliases and Command Line prompt programs, and my main program works by inputting b into the cmd.exe, followed by some filepath names and what not. How would I run those arguments in my python script? So that it mimics the action i am doing in the cmd?

Comment: Can you give some examples? `cmd.exe` is this under Windows, talk of aliases made me think it was Linux/Unix.

Comment: Yes this is Windows. For example I would run a command "b Y TUP TUP010"

b being the program, Y the drive, TUP the directory, and TUP010 the subdirectory

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module. In particular, [subprocess.call](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) will run command line programs for you.

Answer (score 15):

or you can use

```
import os
os.system('your_command')
```

for example:

```
import os
os.system('notepad')
```

will launch the notepad with the command line behind.

hope this helps

Comment: The subprocess module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function. See the Replacing Older Functions with the subprocess Module section in the subprocess documentation for some helpful recipes.

Comment: I've set up an alias so that when I type maya it opens an animation software maya. Yet when I do this, it works for notepad, but not for maya.

Comment: I agree subprocess is way better.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html)

For example, this call bellow gets the output of the program and stores it as a string, using `.call` will help with calling it and for more accurate control use `.Popen`

```
subprocess.check_output(["ipconfig"])
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Sarge](http://sarge.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) - *a wrapper for subprocess which aims to make life easier for anyone who needs to interact with external applications from their Python code.* and [Plumbum](http://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) - *a small yet feature-rich library for shell script-like programs in Python.*