# Python/CMD command

Tags: python, cmd

So I am running a command in my python py file

```
myNewShell = os.system('start "%s" /d "%s" cmd /f:on  /t:0A /k "W:\\Desktop\\alias.bat"' % (myShot, myWorkDir))
```

This opens up a shell

How exactly would I input something into this shell directly from my python script, thus bypassing your actual cmd.exe. I have a bunch of DOSKEYs set up, such as maya which opens up the maya program. How would I add a line of code to my python script, so that it loads the shell with those aliases and inputs my command directly

Comment: You are asking the same question twice. Update your original question and dont make people split the work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741600/running-command-lines-within-your-python-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the powerful and useful [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module

You can then do code like this

```
import subprocess
pro = subprocess.Popen("cmd", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
pro.stdin.write("mybat.bat\n")
pro.stdin.write("myother.bat\n")
pro.stdin.write("start mysillyprogram\n")
pro.stdin.flush()
pro.terminate() # kill the parent
```

Comment: Use the communicate() method when using PIPE, instead of accessing the fd directly... Or, dont even open a stdout here if you dont need it.